# API for auto discount based on customer group Shoopify Plus

Tags: api, automation, shopify

Hi we have a shopify plus store  and we have to provide a auto discount based on the customer groipus. 
Suppose a customr is in vip group he should get automatically 50 % discount.

I can see shopify don't provide this.

**Can you please provide an API reference with which i can detect the customer group and apply discount on his cart.**

Comment: You can achieve this without any API. Just check if the customer has a VIP tag and apply a hidden discount field to the cart. Limit the discount field only to his group.

Comment: i dont want to do this through discount code which will show as applied discount code.

Comment: You need to provide more information here. You want a 50% discount, but you don't want to use a discount. You are contradicting yourself here. Shopify doesn't allow you to modify your variant prices without some kind of a discount applied. There are Shopify Scripts but I don't have not a lot experience there https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/apps/apps-by-shopify/script-editor/ to confirm if this will help you. ( please note Shopify scripts requires you to write Ruby code and the need of Shopify PLUS account )

Comment: i dont want to use any specific discount code , instead of that its more like the discount on order which requires no discount code Yes we are using a Shopify plus and i have basic knowledge of Ruby

Comment: Look into Shopify Scripts then. I worked only once with it a long time ago and I can't remember if it applied any discount or not to the cart itself.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Shopify Script Generator here https://jgodson.github.io/shopify-script-creator/

I use this for creating all our scripts and it makes it so much easier.

I currently have a script which automatically applies free delivery to all customers with a "VIP Platinum" tag from our loyalty program, you can do the same thing for discounts.

tip, don't forget to export and save the file somewhere, this way if you need to edit or add another rule to it you don't need to start from scratch again.

edit: forgot to mention, as per your requirement this doesn't apply a discount code either. you can use the generator to create another script to block discounts from being used with this if you need/want